Как скопировать всё содержимое консоли в строку? | C++
Как скопировать всё содержимое терминала в строку, чтобы можно было с этим содержимым что-то сделать, чтобы изменённое содержимое вставить в терминал?
Если не совсем понятен вопрос, то вот примерно вот так мог бы выглядить код:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    std::string consoleInsd = get_console(); // тут нужно получить содержимое консоли
    int lenght = consoleInsd.length();
    consoleInsd = consoleInsd.substr(0, length - 10); // для примера хочу убрать последние 10 символов
    system("clear");
    std::cout << consoleInsd;

    return 0;
}


Такое не получится, но можно переместить курсор на 10 символов влево и напечатать поверх. Для этого выводи в консоль 10 раз \r
Другие коды https://ru.manpages.org/console_codes/4

Не существует средств языка C++, способных получить содержимое консоли, так как консоль - компонент операционной системы, а не языка.
Если ваша цель - редактировать содержимое консоли, то может быть, попробовать сторонние библиотеки, например, ncurses?

А как это делает ncurses? Вы уверены что нельзя.

@чистов_ n, Я не изучал эту библиотеку, просто читал, что она предназначена для манипуляций с консолью. Если вы уверены, что она не решает задачу автора (с учетом того, что это похоже на проблему молотка), то я удалю ответ.

Мне кажется это должен быть комментарий, а не ответ.

@maestro Я не говорю что это не решает проблему автора. Я говорю противоположенное. Что это как-то можно сделать и просто на c++.
